# Can we have two sets of Azure B2C sign-in custom policies for the application?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a requirement to project different type of B2C sign-in page to end user?
For example,
User type-1: will be using the user name or email-id to sign-in with self service password reset option. (B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN - File 1)

User type-2: Will be signing in only by using the user name and no Forgot password link and self service password reset option provided. (B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN - File 2)

Based on my understanding, I will have to create two different custom policy for user type 1 & 2? Is that right? If yes, how about B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKBASE and B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS files - do I need to have seperate copy of these w.r.t user type please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to keep seperate B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKBASE and B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS files. Just have 2 different relying party poicies. And have 2 seperate User Journeys in Trustframeworkbase file.

Comment: Thanks Sapgar, will try this approach.